# error cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I have an array named : `board_3x3_squars`
It has 9 rows with numbers 1 to 9 in each row.

I want to create a new array with the values of the index of a random value (1 to 9) in each of the rows in array board_3x3_squars.
so for example if value 5 is in index 2 of row 0 in board_3x3_squars
I want the new array for value 5 to be like:
new array = [2]

the for loop is giving me the following error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')"

and I don't know how to solve it.
Code:

```
for (let i = 0; i <= board_3x3_squars.length; i++) {
  let valIndex = [];
  let val = [];
  val = board_3x3_squars[i].indexOf(randmNum());
  valIndex.push(val);
}
```

This is the randNum function **:**

```
let numPick;
const chosenNumPick = [];

function randmNum() {
  let min = Math.ceil(1);
  let max = Math.floor(9);
  numPick = Math.floor(Math.random(1, 9) * (max - min + 1) + min);
  if (chosenNumPick.includes(numPick)) {
    randmNum();
  } else if (chosenNumPick.lenth < 9) {
    chosenNumPick.push(numPick);      }
  return numPick;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`board_3x3_squars[i]` returns a number (a value in the array at index **i**). You are then calling the *indexof* method on this number (`val = board_3x3_squars[i].indexOf(randmNum());`), which is not correct. You can only call *indexof* on an array (e.g. `board_3x3_squars.indexof(randmNum())`)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. I just created a working code snippet. Can you please have a look and let me know what challenges you are facing.

```js
let numPick;
const chosenNumPick = [];
const board_3x3_squars = [[1 , 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]];

function randmNum() {
  let min = Math.ceil(1);
  let max = Math.floor(9);
  numPick = Math.floor(Math.random(1, 9) * (max - min + 1) + min);
  if (chosenNumPick.includes(numPick)) {
    randmNum();
  } else if (chosenNumPick.lenth < 9) {
    chosenNumPick.push(numPick);      }
  return numPick;
}
  
let valIndex = [];

for (let i = 0; i < board_3x3_squars.length; i++) {
  let val = [];
  const randumNum = randmNum();
  val = board_3x3_squars[i].indexOf(randumNum);
  valIndex.push({
    val: randumNum,
    index: val
  });
}

console.log(valIndex);
```